# How to pass current loop value to server : thymeleaf, htmx, Alpine JS?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, alpine.js, htmx

I am using Thymeleaf, htmx, tailwind & alpine js. I am currently looping a list which i am displaying in a table. For each row, there is a button and when the button is clicked I send informations regarding the current row to my controller : item.filename. I would like to know if anybody have any idea for how to get so done ? Thank you for any potential input.

```
<tbody class="flex-1 sm:flex-none">
 <template x-for="item in searchResults">
  <tr class="flex flex-col flex-no wrap sm:table-row mb-2 sm:mb-0">
  <td class="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3" x-text="item.processorName">/td>
  <td class="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3" x-text="item.filename"></td>
  <td class="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3" x-text="item.createdAt"></td>
  <td class="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3" x-text="item.status"></td>
  <td class="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3" x-text="item.completedAt"></td>
  <td class="border-grey-light border  p-3 text-red-400 hover:text-red-600 hover:font-medium cursor-pointer">
    <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-teal-400 px-4 py-1 rounded text-white focus:outline-none" th:attr="hx-get=@{'/modal/filename=' + '${item.filename}'}" hx-trigger="click"
method="get" hx-target="#table" hx-swap="beforeend swap:0.5s">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Do you need to iterate with Alpine (using `x-for`), can't you iterate with Thymeleaf (using `th:each`)?

Comment: no because I am implementing a front end search by alpine JS and since the content is filtered and injected into the DOM by JS i am having to loop by x-for.

Comment: You will probably need to use `x-bind` to have Alpine update the `hx-get` attribute, see https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Thanks for your input. I was able to avoid going through all the javascript by using hx-indicator. Regards mon ami.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hx-indicator from htmx, it avoids all the unnecessary javascript coding.

Comment: does not answer your question

Comment: I was indirectly trying to create the features this tag gives in htmx by plain javascript. I realised it is already made available.